# Displaying images from one table from database in two different div styles

Tags: php, html, css

First I'm sorry for the title but I can't think other way how to explain the case. If someone want can edit it. So here is the case that I have and I can't really figured it out how to made it. This is the HTML part where I have two different div's and 3 columns of images. The problem is that on column 1 and 3 there is large images. The HTML is this:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Start Row -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- First Column -->
       <div class="small-box">
              // image 800x533
       </div> 
       <div class="large-box">
              // image 860x1068
       </div>
    </div> <!-- End First Column -->

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- Second Column -->
       <div class="small-box">
             // image 800x533
       </div>
       <div class="small-box">
             // image 800x533
       </div>
       <div class="small-box">
            // image 800x533
       </div>
    </div> <!-- End Second Column -->

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- Third Column -->
       <div class="large-box">
            // image 860x1068
       </div>
       <div class="small-box">
            // image 800x533
       </div>
 </div>
```

This is the PHP part that I planning to use. It's very simple just load some images from database.

```
 $pdo = Database::connect();

 foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_id LIMIT 7") as $row) 
 {
        // load images images
 }
 Database::disconnect();
```

How to load them in this 3 columns? Is there someone have and idea ho can be done this? Al the images are in one table.

Here is the Jsfiddle I've made how it's look like the gallery. Those 2 images with the panda are the large-box.. others are small-box.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uLwhuvyq/1/)

Comment: What's the problem? You surely know how to create dynamic HTML from PHP? What's in the database, only links to the image files or base64 encoded images?

Comment: I know yes. But I can't figured out how to create that kind htm in php. If it was just one div it's no problem. But here they are mixed small-box, large-box... small, small.. etc. The images in database are links to folder on the host.

Comment: Collect all image paths in an array and then just echo the appropriate path in the correct location, e.g. `<img src="<?php echo $image_paths[2]; ?>" />` for the first image in second column.

Comment: I'm sorry but again I don't understand how.. On every src I must give different image path or no? Can you provide me some example?

Comment: Expand your question: what's actually in the  `// load images images` part? How is the database table defined?

Comment: What I think is to place that html in the loop where is `// load images`. What you mean with `How is the database table defined?`? It's simple table that hold `image_id`, `image_name` and `image_path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a simple database table like IMAGES[id|path|caption]. Then, retrieving the images would be something like:

```
 $images = [];
 $pdo = Database::connect();

 foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_id LIMIT 7") as $row) 
 {
        // load images images
        $images[] = [
            'path' => $row['path'],
            'caption' => $row['caption']
        ];
 }
 Database::disconnect();
```

Next, you can just use your HTML and use some simple function to output the image. First, the PHP function to create an image:

```
function image_html($image, $size = 'small') {
  return '<img src="' . $image['path'] . '" title="' . $image['caption'] . '" class="' . $size . '"/>';
}
```

Then your HTML:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Start Row -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- First Column -->
       <div class="small-box">
              // image 800x533
              <?php echo image_html($images[0]); ?>
       </div> 
       <div class="large-box">
              // image 860x1068
              <?php echo image_html($images[1], 'large'); ?>
       </div>
    </div> <!-- End First Column -->

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- Second Column -->
       <div class="small-box">
             // image 800x533
              <?php echo image_html($images[2]); ?>
       </div>
       <div class="small-box">
             // image 800x533
              <?php echo image_html($images[3]); ?>
       </div>
       <div class="small-box">
            // image 800x533
              <?php echo image_html($images[4]); ?>
       </div>
    </div> <!-- End Second Column -->

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- Third Column -->
       <div class="large-box">
            // image 860x1068
              <?php echo image_html($images[5], 'large'); ?>
       </div>
       <div class="small-box">
            // image 800x533
              <?php echo image_html($images[6]); ?>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. What is mean this error - `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 ... till 6`?

Comment: Also did you mean in the function `image` or `images`?

Comment: Well, you have a basic understanding of PHP, right? `$images` is the array that contains all images from your database. `$image` is the single image information (an array again) used inside the `image_html()` function.

Comment: Yes, I see now. One last thing are those two files in that case? I mean one file `php` and other where is `html`. The I include the php file?

Comment: All of the above code snippets may go into one single PHP file. No need to include anything.

Comment: I've made it like this in your answer. In `<?php ?>` I've add the foreach and the function. Then right after is the html part but got those undefined notice `Notice:  Undefined variable: image...`

Comment: Ok I found the problem but there is another problem. Those images will be dynamic and will return last 7 results from database. I've tried to add another image but still show the first 5-6 results from database and I've put in `ORDER` clause `DESC`

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems you lack some basic understanding of how this works. Try to break down the task into smaller problems and tackle them one at a time. For example, start with how to retrieve specific rows from a database, then maybe PHP loops and if..else clauses and how to combine them into a single working script.

Comment: Thank's again for the answer. What I think is that I don't need to retrieve specific rows from database. I need last X inserted rows.

Comment: Then just add `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7` to the query.

Comment: It doesn't help as I said earlier it just show first 7 results from database. It doesn't matter if I use ASC or DESC..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76441/discussion-between-paul-and-john).